# What is the "Rails Way" to load templated pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am just starting to pick up Ruby on Rails.  I rather like it, but I ran into a roadblock.  I know of two ways to solve a problem but I am curious as to what the "Rails Way" to do this is.

**The Setup**

I have an index page that lists project descriptions.  When a user clicks on a project it brings them to the `show` function of the projects controller.  Projects in the list are loaded from a MySQL database.

**What I Want To Do**

I want to be able to load project specific information on each "Project Page."  This information consists of documentation, code examples, etc.  Each page will have the same general template.

**Way 1**

Store the HTML and text in the MySQL database in a "Sections" table and load all the sections related to that project.  Display each section going down the page.

**Way 2** (The way I would rather do it)

Have a separate view for each project with the full documentation.  Load a specific view based on the project that is loaded in the `show` function

**Comments**

Is there some third way in Rails that I am not used to thinking of since I come from using CodeIgniter?

I am completely up for adapting to what the "Rails Way" is, but I am just not sure what the proper convention for this kind of thing is.

Or is this problem a case of, it does not matter how you do it at all?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, one of the easiest ways is to override default template.(render :action doesn’t run any code in the target action only template)
This is Way2 in your question. Example:

```
def show
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  if @project.has_template?
    render :action => "show_#{@project.template_name}" and return
  end
  render :action => "show"
end
```

In this example directory app/views/projects should have templates for each project
with names like "show.html.erb" for default one and "show_myspecialproject.html.erb" for project with template_name "myspecialproject" , etc....

Template_name is a method that tell you if project has such or should use default, you can put any logic in this method, it can be additional column id table or just template_name can be equal to project name, or it can just check if file exist in current directory.

You can also use partial templates if you want to use show.html.erb because you have code duplications  and keep your templates DRY. 
http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Partials.html 
This way

controller action is default

```
def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])      
end 



in show.html.erb
<h1><%= @project.name %></h1>
<%= render @project.tamplate_name %>
```

In this example all partial templates should start with "_" , 
Ex. : "_myspecialproject.html.erb"

Comment: so, for `"show_#{@project.template_name}"` template_name would be a column in the database that stores the name of the view to load?  What folder would the view need to be in?  Also is there a way to load this in another view?  I want each project page to have the same heading.  Will I just have to duplicate the heading in each view?   I apologize for all the questions, I am very new to Rails and am still picking up on all the conventions.

Comment: I selected this answer because it is easier for me to quickly develop the pages for now.  I will end up switching to the answer by Marlin Pierce down the road once I have the design and sections flushed out.  These are both great ways to do this though.

Answer (score 1):

If each project has the same general template, I don't know what the value is of having different views.

Here's a suggestion to try on for size.

You can store the documentation, code examples, etc. in a sections table, or each type in it's own table.  If you have them in a sections table, include a type field, and use different classes for each type.  Let's say Documentation and CodeExample are two such classes.

Define a has_one in your Project class for each type with a :conditions option.

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :documentation, :conditions => { :type => "Documentation" }
  has_one :code_example, :conditions => { :type => "CodeExample" }
end

class Documentation < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "sections"
  belongs_to :project
end
```

If you want to organize your project show page to include the sections, you can call partials for each section type.

If you want your project show page to have a link or tab (you can implement tabs on the page using links or CSS formatted buttons) go to a show action in a controller for the section type.  Using nested routes for this might be an idea you want to use.

```
resources :projects do
  resource :documentation
  resource :code_example
end
```

These are some ideas.  You might take what you want from my ideas, if you don't want to do it all this way.

Comment: There's some rationale that I think is better in comments than cluttering the example(s).  Also, I realized that I don't know exactly what you are trying to do, so I'm gleaming how you are thinking about it.  If the project show page is always the same one template, then you really wouldn't have an issue.  I suspect you have different views of a project, one of which is documentation, another code example.

Comment: It is more the Rails way to simplify to controllers which just the seven standard actions, and no more than one template per action, but instead proliferating controllers.  So maybe Documentation and CodeExample should have their own controllers.

Comment: Having a class for Documentation and a class for CodeExample, whether they have their own tables or use STI will give you a way for different behavior.  Like if the code example has a formatter for color markup.  This will give you methods you can call from your code example specific template, which avoids using helpers.  Helpers are not bad, but I use them sparingly, instead things usually go in the model.

Comment: I very much like your answer, I am probably going to go with the first answer right now though and move over to yours once I have the sections defined.   The general idea I want the page to end up having is just a straight down list of sections and content. So bigger bold section title, then the content.  The only problem is I do not know if all my projects will have the same sections.  I will definitely keep your suggestions in mind for a different page I am doing though.